# Powershell add to hash table

Tags: sql, powershell

Trying to understand this code.

I understand a hash table is being created.
Then a sql query is run which I omitted but that is piped to a foreach.
The next line is where I am not getting what is happening. The employee_number is coming from the sql query but wouldn't $empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] be $null since it was just created in line 1 of the code.  I can't even really explain this well.

```
$empExtraDepts = @{} 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SQL Query" | foreach {    
     if($empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] -eq $null) {
        $empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] = @()
    }   
    $empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] += $_.a_segment_5.Trim() }
```

Comment: Yes, it would be null on the first sql record processed in the foreach loop, but then on subsequent objects the code is checking to see again if there has been an assignment.  On the first object a key is being added to the hashtable as the employee_number and the value of the is being defined as any empty array `@()`.  In following loops it is checking if the sql object's employee_number has already been created as a key in the hashtable and if it is, don't create it again, just add a_segment_5 to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What* the code does:

- It creates a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) whose:

  - entry *keys* are the distinct employee numbers (`.employee_number` values) returned from your SQL query.
  - entry *values* contain the *array* of all `.a_segment_5` values for a given employee (number), across all rows returned from the query.

*How* it does it:

- `if ($empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] -eq $null)` checks if the hashtable already contains an entry for the employee number at hand (see below for how to improve this test).

  - If not, it (implicitly) creates an entry for that employe number with an *empty array* as the value: `$empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] = @()`

    - Note that *assigning* to a hashtable entry with index syntax (`[$key]`) implicitly creates an entry with key `$key` if it doesn't already exist. If it  already exists, the existing entry's value is replaced.
  - The statement following the `if` statement can therefore rely on `$empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number]` containing an (initially empty) array, and `$empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] += $_.a_segment_5.Trim()` appends a new element to it, loosely speaking , namely the trimmed `.a_segment_5` value of the row at hand. (See below for how to make this more efficient.)

---

The code can be improved in two ways:

- Generally speaking, it's best to place `$null` *on the LHS* of an `-eq` / `-ne` comparison, because if the comparison value is an *array* (as in this case), using it on the RHS can have unexpected results, because `-eq` / `-ne` (and the other comparison operators) act as *filters* with an array-valued LHS, i.e. return the *subarray of matching elements* - see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features).

  - Strictly speaking, testing an entry for `$null` isn't the same as testing whether it *exists* (though in your case that won't make a difference); for the latter, use the `.Contains()` method:

    ```bash
    if ($empExtraDepts.Contains($_.employee_number]))
    ```
- "Growing" an array with `+=` is inefficient, because a *new* array must be allocated behind the scenes every time, given that .NET arrays are *fixed-size* data structures.

  - It is therefore better to use an array-*like* data structure that is efficiently extensible, such as [`[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1).

Therefore:

```bash
# Initialize the results hashtable.
$empExtraDepts = @{}

# Execute the query and process each row returned.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SQL Query" | ForEach-Object {    
  # Does the hashtable already have an entry for the employee number at hand?
  if ($null -eq $empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number]) { # Note the $null on the LHS
    # No -> create the entry with an (initially) empty list as the value.
    $empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number] = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] @()
  }
  # Add the trimmed .a_segment_5 value of the row at hand
  # to the list stored in the entry for the employee number at hand.
  # Note the use of the .Add() method.
  $empExtraDepts[$_.employee_number].Add($_.a_segment_5.Trim())
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you for these detailed explantion!